# symfony entity attribute not recognized when called in twig

Tags: symfony, twig, entity

I have a form in which I want to make values of the input set up by using `{{app.user.mail_2}}` but when I do I get an error:

> Neither the property "mail_2" nor one of the methods "mail_2()", >"getmail_2()"/"ismail_2()"/"hasmail_2()" or "__call()" exist and have public >access in class "BAJ\BookingBundle\Entity\Drivers".

I already used it for name and it works.

Here's my html.twig code

```
      <div class="clear"></div>
                <div id="email-2" class="form_element email-facultatif">
                    <div>2ème e-mail (facultatif)</div>
                    <input type="email" class="email-mobile-width" 
    name="drivers[email_2]" placeholder="EMAIL" value="{{ app.user.mail_2 }}" 
    style="border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;border-top-right-radius: 0px;width: 
    224px;"/>
                    <div class="email-facultatif-block" id="email-2-img"><img
                                src="{{ asset('bundles/bajbooking/images/moin- 
    icon.png') }}" style="width: 41px;"></div>
                </div>
```

and this is my entity

```
 /**
   * Drivers
   *
   * @ORM\Table(name="drivers")
   * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="BAJ\BookingBundle\Repository\DriversRepository ")
   */
   class Drivers extends BaseUser
   {
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="license_date", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $licenseDate;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $title;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="civility", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $civility;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="first_name", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $firstName;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="date_of_brith", type="string", nullable=true)
 */
private $dateOfBrith;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="phone", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $phone;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="address", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $address;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="second_address", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $second_address;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="postal_code", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $postalCode;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="city", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $city;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="country", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $country;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="mail_2", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $mail_2;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="mail_3", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $mail_3;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="mail_4", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $mail_4;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="mail_5", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $mail_5;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="phone_2", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $phone_2;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="phone_3", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $phone_3;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="phone_4", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $phone_4;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="phone_5", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $phone_5;


/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Booking", mappedBy="driver")
 */
private $bookings;

public function __construct() {
    $this->bookings = new ArrayCollection();
    parent::__construct();
}


/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return int
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set licenseDate
 *
 * @param \DateTime $licenseDate
 *
 * @return Drivers
 */
public function setLicenseDate($licenseDate)
{
    $this->licenseDate = $licenseDate;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get licenseDate
 *
 * @return \DateTime
 */
public function getLicenseDate()
{
    return $this->licenseDate;
}

/**
 * Set title
 *
 * @param string $title
 *
 * @return Drivers
 */
public function setTitle($title)
{
    $this->title = $title;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get title
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getTitle()
{
    return $this->title;
}

/**
 * Set civility
 *
 * @param string $civility
 *
 * @return Drivers
 */
public function setCivility($civility)
{
    $this->civility = $civility;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get civility
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getCivility()
{
    return $this->civility;
}

/**
 * Set name
 *
 * @param string $name
 *
 * @return Drivers
 */
public function setName($name)
{
    $this->name = $name;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get name
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getName()
{
    return $this->name;
}

/**
 * Set firstName
 *
 * @param string $firstName
 *
 * @return Drivers
 */
public function setFirstName($firstName)
{
    $this->firstName = $firstName;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get firstName
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getFirstName()
{
    return $this->firstName;
}

/**
 * Set dateOfBrith
 *
 * @param \DateTime $dateOfBrith
 *
 * @return Drivers
 */
public function setDateOfBrith($dateOfBrith)
{
    $this->dateOfBrith = $dateOfBrith;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get dateOfBrith
 *
 * @return \DateTime
 */
public function getDateOfBrith()
{
    return $this->dateOfBrith;
}

/**
 * Add booking
 *
 * @param \BAJ\BookingBundle\Entity\Booking $booking
 *
 * @return Drivers
 */
public function addBooking(\BAJ\BookingBundle\Entity\Booking $booking)
{
    $this->bookings[] = $booking;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove booking
 *
 * @param \BAJ\BookingBundle\Entity\Booking $booking
 */
public function removeBooking(\BAJ\BookingBundle\Entity\Booking $booking)
{
    $this->bookings->removeElement($booking);
}

/**
 * Get bookings
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getBookings()
{
    return $this->bookings;
}

/**
 * Set phone
 *
 * @param string $phone
 *
 * @return Drivers
 */
public function setPhone($phone)
{
    $this->phone = $phone;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get phone
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getPhone()
{
    return $this->phone;
}

/**
 * Set address
 *
 * @param string $address
 *
 * @return Drivers
 */
public function setAddress($address)
{
    $this->address = $address;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get address
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getAddress()
{
    return $this->address;
}

/**
 * Set secondAddress
 *
 * @param string $secondAddress
 *
 * @return Drivers
 */
public function setSecondAddress($secondAddress)
{
    $this->second_address = $secondAddress;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get secondAddress
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getSecondAddress()
{
    return $this->second_address;
}

/**
 * Set postalCode
 *
 * @param string $postalCode
 *
 * @return Drivers
 */
public function setPostalCode($postalCode)
{
    $this->postalCode = $postalCode;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get postalCode
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getPostalCode()
{
    return $this->postalCode;
}

/**
 * Set city
 *
 * @param string $city
 *
 * @return Drivers
 */
public function setCity($city)
{
    $this->city = $city;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get city
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getCity()
{
    return $this->city;
}

/**
 * Set country
 *
 * @param string $country
 *
 * @return Drivers
 */
public function setCountry($country)
{
    $this->country = $country;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get country
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getCountry()
{
    return $this->country;
}

/**
 * Set mail2
 *
 * @param string $mail2
 *
 * @return Drivers
 */
public function setMail2($mail2)
{
    $this->mail_2 = $mail2;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get mail2
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getMail2()
{
    return $this->mail_2;
}

/**
 * Set mail3
 *
 * @param string $mail3
 *
 * @return Drivers
 */
public function setMail3($mail3)
{
    $this->mail_3 = $mail3;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get mail3
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getMail3()
{
    return $this->mail_3;
}

/**
 * Set mail4
 *
 * @param string $mail4
 *
 * @return Drivers
 */
public function setMail4($mail4)
{
    $this->mail_4 = $mail4;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get mail4
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getMail4()
{
    return $this->mail_4;
}

/**
 * Set mail5
 *
 * @param string $mail5
 *
 * @return Drivers
 */
public function setMail5($mail5)
{
    $this->mail_5 = $mail5;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get mail5
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getMail5()
{
    return $this->mail_5;
}

/**
 * Set phone2
 *
 * @param string $phone2
 *
 * @return Drivers
 */
public function setPhone2($phone2)
{
    $this->phone_2 = $phone2;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get phone2
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getPhone2()
{
    return $this->phone_2;
}

/**
 * Set phone3
 *
 * @param string $phone3
 *
 * @return Drivers
 */
public function setPhone3($phone3)
{
    $this->phone_3 = $phone3;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get phone3
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getPhone3()
{
    return $this->phone_3;
}

/**
 * Set phone4
 *
 * @param string $phone4
 *
 * @return Drivers
 */
public function setPhone4($phone4)
{
    $this->phone_4 = $phone4;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get phone4
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getPhone4()
{
    return $this->phone_4;
}

/**
 * Set phone5
 *
 * @param string $phone5
 *
 * @return Drivers
 */
public function setPhone5($phone5)
{
    $this->phone_5 = $phone5;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get phone5
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getPhone5()
{
    return $this->phone_5;
}
}
```

Comment: Post your entity

Comment: i posted it u can look

Answer (score 1):

The "mail_2" property doesn't have public access (which is normal) and the getMail_2() method doesn't exist in your class.

`{{ app.user.getMail2() }}`  or  `{{ app.user.mail2 }}` should work.

Moreover, [it's recommended](https://symfony.com/doc/current/contributing/code/standards.html#naming-conventions) 
*not* to use underscores for variable and method names.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is the line that is throwing the error. The error says the entity "Drivers" does not have the property "mail_2" and you're calling "app.user" which is the fully-authenticated logged-in user.

I think somewhere else on the page you have `driver.email_2` called.